# Usage of the blender logo and copyright

Tags: properties

I have created my own logo. I want to have the blender icon as eyes in my logo. As a tribute and to show that I'm using Blender as my main 3D software.

Wondering if this violates the copyright with blender.

I read through Q & A here: https://www.blender.org/about/logo/
But I'm still unsure if I can use it in my logo.

I also could not find other tags that match "Tradermark, logos, copyright etc". Perhaps somone with access could make a tag for it?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about  legality/licensing. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic/423#423

Comment: Agreed. I did not know about that, but it explains why it lacked tags for the topic. Can I close the question myself? Tried to shut it, but do not know how. I did vote it for closing tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On reading the linked “about logo” page I’d say ‘no’. Mostly due to the paragraph :

> You will visualize and promote your own branding more prominent than
>   you use the Blender logo. The Blender logo only can be used as a
>   secondary brand, which means it has to be clear for an average viewer
>   that this is not an official Blender or Blender Foundation website,
>   publication or product.

IMO, by making the Blender logo part of your logo (the eye) there is no separation between your logo and the Blender logo so it isn’t clear as a “secondary brand”, making it appear to be endorsed or affiliated with Blender.

Comment: Thx for you answer and making it clear for me. 
It sucks, but it`s fair tho. I'll find something else I can do. 
Perhaps someone who knows about a blender logo or something that reminds of blender, which is without copyrights?

Comment: you could make the eye a stylised version of the Blender logo.

Comment: Yes, a distortion of the logo shape may allude to the blender logo without actually being an infringement on the copyright. Perhaps to make that logo wrap the eye and side of head and to have some feather texture to the tips but still resemble the logo.

Comment: Yes, I will see what I`ll do :) thx for the tips guys! :D